# r.surf.contour for large area

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, rasterization

I have a vector file containing contour with 2m accuracy, covering a large area (All Hong Kong).

I tried to generate an elevation raster map with the file, by first rasterized the  vector, using v.to.rast, and then generate the elevation map, by r.surf.contour.

The output file of step 1 (v.to.rast) is approximately 60GB. The resolution is 0.3m.

When I run the second step, I got the error: `unable to allocate 808507328 bytes of memory at raster surf.contour`

I guess it is because the file size is too large. I am using 64 bit version of QGIS 3.6.3. I am not sure whether  the Grass installed is also 64 bit.

My question: is there any better way to do this?
Currently, I am trying to separate the region into multiple pieces

Comment: You can take a look at the following link https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Memory_issues about memory allocation in grass

Comment: Please edit your question and report also the GRASS GIS version (which is the relevant part for the question), thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logical approach is correct, but 60 Gb is a massive raster file: I would first asses if all that detail is really needed. A 0.3 raster over Hong Kong seems a little far, if the input data does not have that resolution. Keep also in mind that the contouring process by definition introduces a smoothing of the data.

If reducing the detail is not an option in your case, you must resort to tiling.

Also, you might want to try `gdal_grid` instead of `v.to.rast`.

### Tiling

Use smaller regions to run `r.surf`. Make sure your raster tiles do overlap, otherwise contours from different tiles will not match do to border artifacts.
To do so:

- Create square tiles as polygons, this will be your base to run `r.surf.contour`
- Buffer (without dissolving) by a reasonable amount (which depends on resolution, interpolation parameters, etc.). Rule of thumb: 5% of the tile width.
- Run `gdal_grid` on each *buffered* tile.
- Run `r.surf.contour` on each *base* tile and the corresponding interpolated raster.
- Check for consistency how contours match at the tiles borders.
- Optionally merge the output contours.

### gdal_grid

```
gdal_grid -txe Xmin Xmax -tye Ymin Ymax -outsize pixel_width pixel_height \
-l input_vector_file \
-zfield name_of_field_with_elevation \
-a nearest:radius1=15.0:radius2=15.0:angle=0.0:nodata=0.0 \
-ot Float32 -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=NONE -co BIGTIFF=IF_NEEDED \
input_vector_file.shp \
output_raster_file_gdal.tif
```

To [find out](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Memory_issues) (*H/T kartoza-geek*) which version of Grass your PC is running, and therefore the maximum addressable memory, which in turn will help you figuring out the tile dimension:

```
# run next line in a GRASS GIS session:
file `which r.contour`
```